How to show product variations in quick product view | Woocomerce
woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart(); is not allowing ajax to work, ajax throughs 500 error, can someone help, when I remove the woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart then it works fine but I wanted to show the product variations.
   // AJAX handler for getting product details
    function ewd_get_product_details() {
        $product_id = intval($_POST['product_id']);
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    
        if ($product) {
            echo '<div style="display: flex; gap: 20px;">';
            echo '<div>' . $product->get_image('full') . '</div>';
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<h2>' . $product->get_name() . '</h2>';
            echo '<div>' . $product->get_short_description() . '</div>'; // Display short description
            echo '<div>'; // Start variation form
    
            // Manually construct add to cart form
            echo '<form class="cart" action="' . esc_url(apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink())) . '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            do_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button');
            woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
            do_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button');
            echo '</form>';
    
            echo '</div>'; // End variation form
    
            echo '<div>' . wc_get_stock_html($product) . '</div>'; // Display stock status
            echo '<div>' . $product->get_price_html() . '</div>';
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url($product->add_to_cart_url()) . '" class="button add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>'; // Add to cart button
            echo '</div>'; // End div for text content
            echo '</div>'; // End flex container
        }
    
        wp_die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ewd_get_product_details', 'ewd_get_product_details'); // Allow AJAX for non-logged in users
    add_action('wp_ajax_ewd_get_product_details', 'ewd_get_product_details'); // Allow AJAX for logged in users;

